P-MOSFET not turning OFF
I am using an IRF9640N P-channel MOSFET to switch a 100 Ω load. Gate is controlled via 2N5551 NPN transistor using a series of resistances. The circuit works perfectly fine up to 40 V of supply voltage with proper output voltage response. However, going beyond it make things different as I am not getting 0 V across the load even at off stage. Interestingly this voltage is equal to 40 V applied voltage even though the MOSFET is rated at 200 V and NPN is rated at 160 V. I have attached the output waveforms for the same. Even if I short the gate and source, the problem persists. Please help.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Green waveform show load response and yellow shows gate-source waveform for 46 V supply and note the offset during MOSFET off state.

Green waveform show load response and yellow shows gate-source waveform for 40 V supply.

Connection of the actual circuit with the gate and source shorted for IRF9640 PMOS.

A close up of shorted gate to source terminals.

The tip for green channel is connected to drain of mosfet and the yellow one to the gate. The other is connected to common ground. Please note the offset in the 46V response

Are we looking at a single pulse and only a single pulse? Or is this part of a PWM waveform? Also, If you put the supply voltage up to 50V, does the offset ride with that? Or does it stay fixed at ~4V?

Or even better: leave the output on (steady-state DC) and sweep the supply voltage up from 35V to 50V. What's the behavior?

Its a PWM, with very small duty cycle. If we sweep from 35-50V offset does change with that and rather linearly. I have tried to simply short the gate and source (MOSFET OFF) and I am still seeing this offset above 40V.

And your ground probe is directly on R2? What if you put a multimeter directly across the resistor? Is there truly voltage across the resistor in the off state? And if not, what is it over 40V supply voltage?

The green waveform is across resistor and there is voltage across the resistor in off state. If I apply 45V, it would be 5V at off state, If I apply 60V, it would be 20V. Like that. The pulse increases upto 40V, but then moves up with a this DC offset.

I would try a new MOSFET. could be damaged. This time, just leave the load, the MOSFET and R1 in the circuit. Sweep the supply from 35V to 50V to make sure the MOSFET is off the whole time. If not, you might have a bad batch of MOSFETs. If that works, try again with the rest of the circuit.

As an unrelated side note: you do have a resistor between the NPN transistor and the Arduino, right?

I tried with other MOSFET, worked exactly same. The resistor is merely 10 ohm. Should I increase the value?

No. That's not going to do anything. If you can't keep the MOSFET off from what I suggested, you have a component problem and your circuit problem will remain inconclusive until you have a MOSFET that stays off while the Gate is tied to Vsupply (with or without a resistor).

Can you suggest me some other P Mosfet? My operating conditions demand 70-80V operation with around 1% duty cycle @100Hz.

From a specification standpoint, your MOSFET seems fine. You can use any other MOSFET with similar specs, but there seems to be something wrong with your specific MOSFETs. But personally, I would use a MOSFET with much lower Rds(ON). This has nothing to do with your problem, BTW.

Thanks for help

Your MOSFET seams to behave like a 40 V zener diode in the off state. This is very unusual. Can you measure the load current at a supply of 60 V for verification? Is there really 200 mA flowing in the off state?

I can't get your point to measure the current. If there is a voltage across the resistor in off state, there must be some current flowing through it.

@MOSFET, I just tried to change the load resistor, from 100 ohm to 1K ohm and then back to 10 ohm. I am observing a very weird trend.

@Goeld So what is the trend?

I have reported that the offset is for 40V or more. However, using a high load resistance (1k ohm) resulted in even lower voltage where the mosfet begins to behave separately (at 32V).

Do a separate test with just the MOSFET with shorted gate to source and a load resistor then measure the response as you vary the supply voltage. You don't need a circuit board just the components.

I have already done that. And response is no different.

In that case you have a bad device(s). It doesn't possible to just be a connection issue. Get a new/different component.

@KevinWhite, on similar grounds, I have used a NMOS at low side (with gate and source shorted to keep VGS=0) to check the offset voltage at 65V, even then I am getting some offset, albeit a lower value than the one with PMOS under similar condition.

@Goeld Post a picture of your set up with just the MOSFET gate shorted. With the instrumentation attached. TBH, it sounds like you are measuring wrong.

Maybe the mosfet gate at some point was connected by mistake to GND, then with 40V at the source it could have damaged it. Maybe even floating around zero. E.g. changing wires with the circuit powered, etc.  Just thinking in possible explanations.

I have done all these stuff, using different MOSFETs of same model. I repeat the circuit works absolutely fine below 40V. The behavior is observed only for voltages above it.

Maybe the problem is the breadboard, some are rated for 15V to 30V maximum.  You have 40V between drain and source in adjacent rows.

Maybe, but I have changed to a high side N-MOSFET from existing P-MOSFET (obviously with drain connected to voltage source, source to load and shorted the gate to source). Under similar conditions, NMOS is blocking the voltage pretty well.

@Goeld How about this, forget the resistor all together. And just put the MOSFET in series with your meter in Ammeter mode at the uA range. I suspect your getting voltage across the resistor due to high leakage current in the MOSFET. You can measure this. while changing the voltage across that arrangement.

Ok, but the breadboard rows could produce capacitances somewhere, I don't know. Just to discard, remove the breadboard and connect the mosfet with clips or cocodrile cables, or soldered wires. If it still conducts, then it's the mosfet.

@Gos, tried, it didn't work out.

@MOSFET I don't have ammeter. But I have found a solution. I have replaced the PMOS with NMOS and using bootstrap for switching. Although it made things tricky, this seem to work for me as of now.

Where did you get the mosfets? could be that they are fake or relabeled?  that's not uncommon in aliexpress and other places.  Because, with the last test, it's just you against the mosfet, nothing else in the middle, right?

ElectronicsComp.in
